# Determine whether each of the following functions is uniformly continuous on the given interval.

Tags: uniform-continuity

I am totally lost on this question. I have looked at similar examples and just do not understand how to solve the following examples. Thank you in advance for any help!

a.) $f(x) = x^4-4x+7, I= [1,2]$

b.) $f(x) = \frac {x+2}x, I= (0,1]$

Comment: Hint on (b): if the derivative of a function increases without bound on an interval, then the function cannot be uniformly continuous on that interval.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know the definition of uniform continuity?

Comment: I do know the definition but I do not understand how to apply it to these particular examples.

Comment: Try to relate the definition of uniform continuity with the fact that the derivative (when it exists, as in these cases) is bounded. Then looking at the derivative should help you a lot. Also, there is a theorem, by Heine and Cantor, which could help in case a).

Comment: I still don't understand how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem that states that every continuous function defined in a compact set is uniformly continuous. The difference is that on uniform continuity, $\delta$ does not depend on $x$, it only depends on $\varepsilon$. 
Given a function $f$, we say that $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$ if $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k |x - y|$, for all $x,y$ in $f$'s domain. Every Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous. (the converse is false!)
If the function is defined on an interval, and has limited derivative, let's say, $|f'(x)| \leq k$, for all $x$ in the interval, then we have $$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(c) (x - y)| = |f'(c)||x-y| \leq k|x - y|$$
for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$.  Try to use all this information. Ok?

Comment: I know all this Information but I do not understand how to apply it to these specific examples :(

Comment: @Ivo Terek: the c you used as a bound isn't necessarily the same as  the one in the mean value theorem

Comment: I am totally confused now!

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realized I had used c for everything. I edited the answer, please see if you can understand now.